# How can I update inventory based on products listed in a Bill of Materials

Tags: mysql, sql, adventureworks

I want to create an stored procedure to 'issue raw materials' from inventory into production.

In plain English I want to prompt the user to enter a ProductID, then pull up the Bill of Materials for the specified ProductID, then subtract the components listed in the BOM from Inventory. (I understand how to update a single item, but I'm wondering if there is a way to update multiple inventory records at once based on the parts that are listed in the BOM)

This is what I have so far. https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTAAL.png (Please click image link)

I want to take the quantity of components requried to build ProductID 794, and subtract them from the Inventory.

I'm new to SQL, and playing around with the AdventureWorks2012 database. Any help is very much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Specify your sample data and expected output

Comment: See syntax of UPDATE using JOINS in MySQL for multiple row update

Comment: Oops! I have specified my data and expected output to help make it more clear.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query